# extracting a text from a large content using php

Tags: php

I have  a text and i need to find out a text which is in double quotes . foe example

```
this is the "dummy text for the" content
```

i need to get the value as `dummy text for the`

Does any one know how to get the this using php?

or any php functions for this ?

thanks

Comment: Use `preg_match()` check docs for details http://php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$subject = 'this is the "dummy text for the" content';
$pattern = '/"(.*?)"/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo $matches[0][1];
?>
```